# SPARQL SKOS:broaderTransitive

Tags: tags, sparql, fuseki, skos

I'm using Fuseki server to update and query my ontology ,
I need to use  SKOS concept to create Hierarchical tag relation ,
for exemple i Hava this Hierarchical relation

A------------>B--------------------->C
A in relation with B and B in relation with C so A is in relation with C
so I use this SPARQL query to add those relations :

```
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
 INSERT DATA  {
 <A> skos:broaderTransitive <B>.
 <B> skos:narrowerTransitive <A> .

}
```

And

```
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
  PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
  INSERT DATA  {
  <B> skos:broaderTransitive <C>.
  <C> skos:narrowerTransitive <B> .

  }
```

and when i need to get  the result i use :

```
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
    select * where { <A> skos:broaderTransitive ?x}
```

And i get only B and i don't get B & C

i don't know if i need to add something because i have a problem with inference ...
I don't know that i need to do, someone have an idea ?
thanks

Comment: How should Fuseki know that the relation is transitive?! It's just plain SPARQL that you're using - even a standard reasoning profile won't help here. Either you add a custom rule set using the generic rule reasoner of Jena or even simpler, use SPARQL 1.1 property paths: `select * where { <A> skos:broaderTransitive* ?x}`

Comment: AKSW thanks ;) select * where { <A> skos:broaderTransitive+ ?x} is what i need .